# how can I fire a bullet that goes through my crosshair

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm doing a shooter game in actionscript 3.0.
I already have the mouseclick event working but now to be more funny I want to fire a bullet on  i click in the mouse.
My mouse is already a crosshair movieclip and now I want that bullet goes trough my crosshair.
I already did bullets going in x or y directions, but to go through my crosshair I dont know how can I do that.
Someone already tried this and can give me a help?

Answer (score 0):

When you click the mouse, try to rotate your bullet to make it points to the mouse direction.

Here is some example about [matrix rotation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ddb.html)